# Cannot Binding ImageSource in Content Dialog UWP

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp-xaml

I put image in Content Dialog but I cannot see any image fetched from the source. It seems that the image source cannot binding from the view model. However it works well with Page

This is my XAML of Content Dialog

```
<ContentDialog
x:Class="SmartEducation.App.Teacher.ContentViewer.Views.SketchDetailPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SmartEducation.App.Teacher.ContentViewer.Views"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:uwpControls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="Student's Sketch"
CloseButtonText="Cancel"
DefaultButton="Primary"
Background="White" Width="750" Height="500">
    <RelativePanel>
            <ScrollViewer  x:Name="scrollView" ZoomMode="Enabled" DoubleTapped="ScrollViewer_DoubleTapped" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="1">
            <StackPanel Background="White" Width="750" Height="500">
                <Image Name="imgSketch" Source="{Binding ImageUri}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
    </RelativePanel>
```

I already add ViewModel to DataContext in my xaml.cs

```
private SketchDetailPageViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return DataContext as SketchDetailPageViewModel; }
    }

    public SketchDetailPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
```

I put the ImageUri in my ViewModel

```
private string _imgContent;
    public string ImageUri
    {
        get { return _imgContent; }
        set
        {
            _imgContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ImageUri));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please make sure the ImageUri has an image resource reference. In your xaml.cs code, just providing a `ViewModel` property by your following code can not set the dialog's data context, so it will not get the image source.

```
private SketchDetailPageViewModel ViewModel
{
    get { return DataContext as SketchDetailPageViewModel; }
}
```

You can just configure the dialog's data context by the following code in the dialog's xaml.cs,

```
public SketchDetailPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new SketchDetailPageViewModel() { ImageUri= "ms-appx:///Assets/Image.png" };
}
```

If you put the image source in the ViewModel. Such as,

```
 private string _imgContent= "ms-appx:///Assets/Image.png";
 public string ImageUri
 {
     get { return _imgContent; }
     set
     {
         _imgContent = value;
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ImageUri));
     }
 }
```

Then you can set the page data context on the XAML of Content Dialog,

```
<ContentDialog
    ...
    Background="White" Width="750" Height="500">
    <ContentDialog.DataContext>
        <local:SketchDetailPageViewModel/>
    </ContentDialog.DataContext>

    <RelativePanel>
        <ScrollViewer  x:Name="scrollView" ZoomMode="Enabled"
                       DoubleTapped="ScrollViewer_DoubleTapped"
                       HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                       HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" 
                       MinZoomFactor="1">
            <StackPanel Background="White" Width="750" Height="500">
                <Image Name="imgSketch" Source="{Binding ImageUri}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </RelativePanel>
</ContentDialog>
```

Or you can set the data context in the xaml.cs,

```
public SketchDetailPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new SketchDetailPageViewModel();
}
```

------ **Update** ------

> but the binding image uri doesn't change although image uri of source change

If you want to change the image by changing the image uri, you can expose the dialog's data context as the following code, meanwhile, your SketchDetailPageViewModel should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. It seems you have implement the interface, here is a simple example,

SketchDetailPageViewModel class,

```
internal class SketchDetailPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _imgContent;
    public string ImageUri
    {
        get { return _imgContent; }
        set
        {
            _imgContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ImageUri));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

class SketchDetailPage : ContentDialog,

```
public SketchDetailPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new SketchDetailPageViewModel() { ImageUri= "ms-appx:///Assets/Image.png" };
}

internal SketchDetailPageViewModel ViewModel
{
    get { return DataContext as SketchDetailPageViewModel; }
}
```

you can change the image when you use the `SketchDetailPage` dialog,

```
 private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     SketchDetailPage dialog = new SketchDetailPage();
     //change the dialog image 
     dialog.ViewModel.ImageUri = "ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png";
     await dialog.ShowAsync();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the binding image uri doesn't change although image uri of source change.

Comment: @quynhnguyen68 I have added the **update** part, you can check it. If it is still not what you want, please provide a simple sample and clarify your issue so that we can talk it on the same point.

Comment: Actually in my ViewModel, I use Messenger.Default.Register to send ImageUri from another to this ViewModel. Therefore, ImageUri must be change when it receive the message, I have debugged, the ViewModel received correct message and change ImageUri, but I don't why the Content Dialog always show instance uri set from contrustor  new SketchDetailPageViewModel() { ImageUri= "ms-appx:///Assets/Image.png" };

Comment: Please provide a simple sample to help me see your project. As what I can see, it works well in my side by changing the viewmodel's ImageUri.